# Meaning of 'make' in this phrase

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> a way of criticizing people or ideas in a humorous way, especially in order to make a political point, or a piece of writing that uses this style
>   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satire

Above the phrase, What does 'make' mean? It is just 'to produce something'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is *to make a point*: "To state or demonstrate something of particular importance." (the first definition [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+point))